# Automatically execute a PHP script when JSON changes detected

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, onesignal

Apologies for my slight newbieness...

I need a javascript (or php) script that will automatically check a JSON file (via HasOffers API call) for changes and then execute a php script (which I already have -- it utilizes OneSignal to send a push notification to my phone) once changes are detected.

So here's my code for calling the API in javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId=SomeNetwork&Target=Affiliate_Report&Method=getStats&api_key=2c0ce8e72df0802c900d1fb6bd34e&fields%5B%5D=Stat.conversions&filters%5BStat.date%5D%5Bconditional%5D=EQUAL_TO&filters%5BStat.date%5D%5Bvalues%5D=2016-01-25', true);

console.log(xhr);
  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function () {
     var repos = JSON.parse(xhr.response), i, reposHTML = "";
     for (i = 0; i < repos.response.data.data.length; i++) {
       reposHTML += repos.response.data.data[i].Stat.conversions;

     }
     document.getElementById("fetch").innerHTML = reposHTML;

  };

  xhr.onerror = function () {
     alert('error making the request.');
  };

xhr.send();
```

How can I integrate a javascript code into this which "listens" for changes in the API/JSON file (specifically a numerical value inside  response.data.data[0].Stat.conversions within JSON file), and then executes another php file that I have when the number goes up by one increment?

So if within the JSON file the Stat.conversions = 30, and then it goes to 31, I want the javascript to automatically execute my php script.

I hope that is clear enough. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything else.

Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure how you see that javascript in browser will help. Browser has to be open to the page for it to work. Use a cron job in php to monitor api changes

Comment: Thanks for your reply man. Yeah I just wasn't sure what the best way would be. Can you give me a quick example of a php script that would monitor api changes and how I'd execute it with a cron job? Thanks again!

Comment: no ... that's a bit too much of a request for this site. You can use cURL to get data from same url shown above. Then will need to store some sort of history to compare to. Not hard to research CRON and cURL

Comment: You could call a small script that makes a hash over the result of the api  call and stores it in a file or db.  Next time it is called it reads that checksum, calls the api again, makes a new checksum and calls the other script if the two hashes don't match.